# I am having trouble with my Codeigniter 3 application. After I have uploaded my app to ubuntu server, and when I login, it returns back to localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this in my config.php

$config['url_suffix'] = 'http://www.example.net/appname/';

after I load www.example.com

it returns back to localhost/appname

Answer (score 1):

You have to set base url in config.php

$config['base_url'] ="Your project url";

Answer (score 1):

change your base url in your config.php file

```
$config['base_url'] ="your server url";
```

Comment: it does not have base_url. I am using CodeIgniter3. I guess ci2 has different file and folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

Do a directory search in your IDE for the term localhost, this should bring up where it's mentioned and potentially redirects.

Also, pay particular attention to your .htaccess file.